# AWS Cloudformation - Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to create a template that associates cidr with an existent vpc. So I don't want to use the template to also create the vpc. But I am having issues in how to reference to that specific vpc

My current template

```
Resources:
  VPC:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPC
    Properties:
      VpcId:
       Ref: vpc-123456
  VpcCidrBlock:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock
    Properties:
      VpcId:  !Ref VPC
      CidrBlock: 192.0.0.0/24
  VpcCidrBlockIpv6:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock
    Properties:
      VpcId:  !Ref VPC
      AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock: true

Outputs:
  CidrBlockAssociation:
    Value: !Select [ 0, !GetAtt VPC.CidrBlockAssociations ]
```

Comment: Can you share the full error message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must reference the existing construct, not create a new one:

```
Resources:
  VpcCidrBlock:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock
    Properties:
      VpcId:  !Ref ExistingVpc
      CidrBlock: 192.0.0.0/24
  VpcCidrBlockIpv6:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCCidrBlock
    Properties:
      VpcId:  !Ref ExistingVpc
      AmazonProvidedIpv6CidrBlock: true

Outputs:
  CidrBlockAssociation:
    Value: !Select [ 0, !GetAtt VPC.CidrBlockAssociations ]
```

If your existing vpc is not already in cloudformation, the you must first import it:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/resource-import.html